# How to run all tests when I click F5 in Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, mstest

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2008 professional. There are three projects, a Windows Form project and two MSTEST projects. The Windows Form project is set as the startup.

When I click F5 to run the Windows Form project in debug mode, I would like to get all the tests to run from both MSTEST projects.

I tried starting all three projects on startup, but got an error message when clicking F5 that only one test result can run at a time. The Windows Form project ran and so did the first MSTEST project.

Is what I want to do possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the tumbleweed badge I received for this question, it might not be possible to do this.